# Does VirtualList (V23) supports Grid Layout

Tags: vaadin

Does VirtualList -https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/virtual-list
like IronList supports Grid Layout, if so how can i enable that ?

As per the documentation, Iam not able to find it https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/virtuallist/VirtualList.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, Virtual List does not support that feature.